# My extension tab is blocked by chrome after a callback

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a chrome extension with plasmo, I use auth0 for authentication, after logging into the auth0 page, I have a callback to a tab in my extension to manage the token (chrome-extension://.../tabs/loginSuccess.html?code=...). That's where the problem comes in, I get this message: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

However, when I get this error and I click on the url and press enter, it works and the page is no longer blocked.

I'd like to know how to avoid being blocked by Chrome, thanks for your help.

I've added the following to host_permissions: chrome-extension://*

I even added the tabs permission (which I later removed because Google told me I wasn't using it in my extension).

Comment: Add the html path to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).